# How to export data from Delta table in Databricks and write to txt file

Tags: python, export, databricks, delta

I have a delta table with 20 columns and around 5.23 million rows. Some of the columns are complex datatypes. I want to export data from the table and write to .txt files using python with a header row using tab (\t) field delimiter and 50,000 rows of data in each file. I am pretty new to Databricks and python and need to have a solution. Please write the full code and not just logic.

Thanks in advance.

Tried searching no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the 50,000 record count per file have to be exact? If not 5.32e6/50,000 is roughly 106, so if we repartition data into 106 partitions, it's gonna give us files with roughly 50,000 records:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.read.format('delta').load('<path to table>')
record_count = df.count()
(
    df
    .select(*[f.col(element).cast(StringType()).alias(element) for element in df.columns]) #To take care of complex data types
    .repartition(int(record_count/50000))
    .write.option('delimiter', '\t').option('header', True).csv('<write destination>')
)

#since you're using Databricks and if you absolutely care about the file extension being .txt
files = dbutils.fs.ls('<write destination>')
for element in flies:
    dbutils.fs.mv(element.path, element.path.replace('.csv', '.txt'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code 50000 is the max records in each file and I am looking at a max 100 files.                                 I am getting error  ": name 'f' is not defined".  Do I need to define each column name or would the above code take all columns.

Comment: Even if the column headers are not in the file, it is ok. Can add later.

Comment: You gotta add import pyspark.sql.functions as f to the top of the solution.

Comment: Yes, it works. I have one question though. When I open the files the data is coming as \\"0\\"  There is additional \\ before " for all files. Any inputs appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It must have something to do with `escape` or `quote` character options. You can find the documentation about it in this link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv.html. You can play with the options you have to find the write combination that matches what you need.